# Only secondary display functioning after generating xorg.conf for Nvidia

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, nvidia, multi-monitor

I am running Pop!_OS on a laptop with an onboard Nvidia GPU. As usual, my secondary monitor has screen tearing issues with Nvidia linux drivers. This is fixed by enable Force Full Composition Pipeline. I added the following lines to my xorg.conf.

```
Option         "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
Option         "AllowIndirectGLXProtocal" "off"
Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
```

Upon rebooting, only my second monitor (but primary display), connected through HDMI, is functioning. I think this may be related to my laptop display being a PRIME display. I believe even manually saving any sort of xorg.conf from nvidia server settings results in this problem. So, why does this issue only occur if a have a xorg.conf generated?
This is my entire xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
    Option         "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
    Option         "AllowIndirectGLXProtocal" "off"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "VIZ E241-A1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     58.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Thanks,

Comment: Post here as well https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148